# Designing a model that can cope with dynamic field names that follow a set pattern

Tags: python, pydantic

I'd like to create a Pydantic model for the following example dictionary:

```
{"response_code_count/R1": 23, "response_code_count/PX1": 58, "some_other_field": "some_other_value"}
```

The challenge is that whilst the `response_code_count` keys follow the same format, the actual code after the forward slash can be anything.

Is there a way to use a model structure that converts all `response_code_count` key/value pairs into a list of sub-models?

Something like the below:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List


class ResponseCodeCount(BaseModel):
    response_code: str
    count: int
    
    
class Response(BaseModel):
    response_code_counts: List[ResponseCodeCount]
    some_other_field: str
```

If not then what would be a way of designing my models such that I can validate and then access dynamic input keys that follow a consistent pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a generic Pydantic pattern to handle this case. However you can always work with a custom model validator, such as:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator
from typing import List

data = {"response_code_count/R1": 23, "response_code_count/PX1": 58, "some_other_field": "some_other_value"}


class ResponseCodeCount(BaseModel):
    response_code: str
    count: int
    
    
class Response(BaseModel):
    response_code_counts: List[ResponseCodeCount]
    some_other_field: str

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, values):
        data = {}

        common_key = "response_code_counts"

        for key, value in values.items():
            if key.startswith("response_code_count/"):
                _, code = key.split("/")
                data.setdefault(common_key, [])
                data[common_key].append({"response_code": code, "count": value})
            else:
                data[key] = value

        return data
    
print(Response(**data))
```

Which prints:

```
response_code_counts=[ResponseCodeCount(response_code='R1', count=23), ResponseCodeCount(response_code='PX1', count=58)] some_other_field='some_other_value'
```

I hope the helps!